# How to convert a System.String type to Chart (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, charts

I designed a WinForms application on VS2022, where a lot of charts are created in Designer. In order to save code and not to define each chart separately I would like to create a Sub, so that depending on input parameters different charts to be created - for example each chart has different number of series, different colors, titles and so on. Input parameters are taken from a MySQL table. The first column in this table is the Chart name. My idea is to read each row of the table and to pass the parameters to the Sub and Sub to be executed for each chart.

My problem is that I cannot convert the string "Chart1" from MySQL table to the corresponding object name "Chart1" from System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart in Designer.

Sub definition looks like:

`Public Sub ChCDR(ch As Chart, Tab As DataTable,serNo As Integer, title As String, legend As String, zero As Integer, yname As String, y2name As String)`

I tried CType-ing the string to Chart, but there was an exception "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart'. Calling the Sub looks like following:

`ChCDR(CType(TabKPI.Rows(0)(0), Chart), TabCell, TabKPI.Rows(0)(1).ToString, TabKPI.Rows(0)(2),TabKPI.Rows(0)(3), TabKPI.Rows(0)(14).ToString, TabKPI.Rows(0)(12), TabKPI.Rows(0)(13))`

I would appreciate a help on this problem or some kind of solution.

Comment: [Form.Controls.Find("TheChildName", true)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find)

Comment: @Jimi, thanks a lot. Your suggestion solved my issue. I tuned your idea to look like:  `Me.Controls.Find(TabKPI.Rows(0)(0), True).FirstOrDefault()`, so that now calling the sub is following: `ChCDR(Me.Controls.Find(TabKPI.Rows(0)(0), True).FirstOrDefault(), TabCell, TabKPI.Rows(0)(1).ToString, TabKPI.Rows(0)(2),TabKPI.Rows(0)(3), TabKPI.Rows(0)(14).ToString, TabKPI.Rows(0)(12), TabKPI.Rows(0)(13))`